# preg_match regular grammar and financial symbols

Tags: php, regex

I am terrible at writing expressions,  I need to allow only A-Z a-z 0-9 .,!$%&:- and spaces, basically what you would find in english grammar and financial transactions.

I have `!preg_match("/^[0-9A-Za-z\\- \&\!\.\,\(\)\$\?\%\\']+$/` but it seems cluttered, for lack of a better term.

Comment: I don't know php, but in many implementations of regex `\w` is a synonym for `[A-Za-z0-9-]`

Comment: `\w` would replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (underscore, not hyphen)

Comment: @Hambone: this includes the underscore, which is not allowed.

Comment: fyi: you don't need to escape all the characters in a class like that, generally only `]\^-` needs to be escaped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `[a-z]`, just by adding the case-insensitive flag `i`. Then you can also replace `[0-9]` with `\d`. And you only need to espace characters with special meanings.

```
/^[a-z\d&!\.,()$?%\\' -]+$/i
```